# Is there a way to use DirectXTex without Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

So far, I tried to do this with my DirectX 11 project to load a texture:

I downloaded DirectXTex source, included source files into my project and tried to compile, but got errors. I got errors from these header files: `WICTextureLoader.h`, `DDSTextureLoader.h`, and `DirectXTex.h`. The errors were from header files, and not my own code. Then, I tried `WICTextureLoader11.h` and `DDSTextureLoader11.h`, and the error that I got was `undefined reference to the function CreateWICTextureFromFile()...` (or the same, but with DDS).

I think, the problem here could be that the compiler (I use Clang/GCC) cannot find the `.lib` file? However, some people here mentioned that you could just throw the source files into your folder and everything would be OK. Seems like, it's not OK for me. If this is the problem, is there a way to get the binaries (`.lib`) without going through VS installation and other stuff?

Comment: It is usually not safe to use binaries compiled in c++ with a different compiler or in some cases a different version of the same compiler (older Visual Studio versions than 2015 are are all binary incompatible). However id this is a windows OS api it will likely be `c`

Comment: Now that I look at the source code [https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex) this is a `c++` project with full source code. You should use `CMake` to generate a MinGW makefiles project and build that project using MinGW

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for a tip. So I tried to download Cmake and did the next: I used Cmake GUI and chose to generate a MinGW Makefile. But since I'm unfamiliar with both of those, I didn't know what to do next. I got a folder with a Makefile that I tried to run, but got many errors. So I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: ***I got a folder with a Makefile that I tried to run, but got many errors.*** Likely then Microsoft did not make this library compatible with other compilers. My advice is to use Visual Studio 2019 and avoid the pain of having to port the code to a different compiler.

Comment: @drescherjm the github page of DirectXTex states that "_This code is designed to build with ... clang_". Another thing that I don't understand, is that as Chuck Walbourn himself answered here that you could drop both header/cpp files into the project and everything should be fine. I'll try to do something again with cmake/makefile, until I get an answer, would be sad if I'll end up installing VS  (which I really don't like) again.

Comment: clang has Visual Studio compatibility described here: [https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html)

Comment: @drescherjm well, that implies that I need to get VS/MSVC :) I'm going to stubbornly continue trying to find a no-VS way of making things work. Right now I'm trying to load a texture through a deprecated function from d3dx11tex.h header file that also throws errors. Thanks for tips, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DirectXTex library can be built with clang/LLVM for Windows or Visual C++. The project includes a [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) for building the DirectXTex library, and optionally the command-line tools, using CMake. If you have your own make solution, you can work out the details by referencing that file.

To use the DirectXTex library functions (a.k.a. `LoadWICFromFile`, `Compress`, etc.), you need to link to the DirectXTex library, which you can do in CMake via `add_subdirectory` and `target_link_libraries`. You also need to add the include path:

To use it from your own CMake:

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../DirectXTex ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/CMake/DirectXTex)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} DirectXTex)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ../DirectXTex/DirectXTex)
```

Keep in mind that the DirectXTex package *also* includes standalone modules (DDSTextureLoader, WICTextureLoader, and ScreenGrab) that are intended for use *instead* of DirectXTex if you want basic runtime loading without all the code required for conversion, resize, compression, etc.

To use stand-alone modules, you need to add *both* the header and the .cpp file to your project--they are *not* in the DirectXTex.lib.

**So in your case**, include from [this directory](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/tree/master/WICTextureLoader) both `WICTextureLoader11.h` and `WICTextureLoader11.cpp` to get the Direct3D 11 version of `CreateWICTextureFromFile`. The reason you got a link error is that you didn't add the cpp file to your project.

> The [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) also includes `DDSTextureLoader`, `WICTextureLoader`, and `ScreenGrab`. These versions are integrated in the `DirectXTK.lib`. Instead of using DirectXTex at all, you could use that project's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) and reference it as:

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../DirectXT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/CMake/DirectXTK)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} DirectXTK)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ../DirectXTK/Inc)
```

See the [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader) documentation and [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression/).

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. When I include both _.h_ and _.cpp_ files into my project, I still get errors: more errors with WIC (e.g. _"use of undeclared identifier 'GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppRGBAFloat'; did you mean 'GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppRGBFloat'"_) and lesser with DDS (e.g. _"use of undeclared identifier 'FileStandardInfo'"_). 

Edit: also, I'm not using MSVC.

Comment: To clarify, the errors don't come from my project's code, but from the _WICTextureLoader11.cpp_.

Comment: Your project needs to link with system libraries that provide the required GUIDs ``dxguid.lib``, ``uuid.lib``. I have CMake files for my various Visual Studio simple DirectX project templates as well. See [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_win32_dr/CMakeLists.txt)

Comment: maybe the errors that I got were not related to the linking process, but I'm not sure, since I didn't see the end of the list (`fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now`). I included libraries listed in your _CMakeList.txt_ example anyway, but I still get the same fatal error. I don't use Cmake to build my project (I'm doing it with a simple batch file), so I'm not sure if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

So, I resolved the issue by giving up and installing the Visual Studio. However, I ended up compiling with Clang; but, instead of linking to GCC, I link to MSVC (otherwise, I'll get errors referring to `vcruntime.h`).

The original problem was that I wanted to use GCC in order to work with DirectX 11, but when it came to the point when I needed to load a texture, it was unfortunate that the D3DX (d3dx11.h) function that I wanted to use was deprecated in favor of D3D implementations: instead of using `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile`, I should consider using [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex) that has the function that I need (`CreateWICTextureFromFile`).

Well, I downloaded and did (kinda) everything that Chuck Walbourn suggested:

1. Download DirectXTex.
2. Move the *DirectXTex* subfolder somewhere (you will later link to it); my location example: `I:\Projects\VS\Real_DirectX11\common\include\DirectXTex`
3. In your project's source (in my case, I just have main.cpp), #include <DirectXTex.h> (not in quotes, because I'm going to link to it).
4. Take two files from the subfolder *WICTextureLoader*: `WICTextureLoader11.cpp` and `WICTextureLoader11.h`.
5. And put them into my project's source (or maybe you want to link them).
6. Inside my `main.cpp`, I #include both of those files (.h/.cpp):

Nothing works, I get link errors (many errors!). I decided to give up and install Visual Studio again (I'm saying again, because at one point I got into OpenGL and started preferring portable solutions; and much simplistic, since my project folder has only the source code and asset files).

Seems like, VS is getting faster in its loading speeds (not compilation!), so maybe it's not that bad after all. Nope. I download the DirectXTex through NuGet package manager and probably did everything for the thing to work. Well, it kinda works, except I get irrelevant errors this time that I didn't get when I was compiling with GCC: my shaders don't compile! Oh no, where did I screw up? I have no idea! Setting the preferences for each files (VS, target version, etc.), nothing helps.

OK, let's get back to my compiler, except this time I'm using Clang ([LLVM 10.0 Windows 64-bit](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-10.0.0/LLVM-10.0.0-win64.exe)) and I link to MSVC (you have it after installing Visual Studio). How? I change my Environment Variable PATHs from GCC's to MSVC's:

**include**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include
```

**lib**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x64
```

**lib32**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x86
```

And, just in case, also included **bin**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\Hostx64\x64
```

Then, I use a batch file to compile my thing:

**build.bat**

```
@echo off

set filename=%1

clang++ ^
%cd%\src\%1.cpp ^
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" ^
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um" ^
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" ^
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared" ^
-I"I:\Projects\VS\Real_DirectX11\common\include\DirectXTex" ^
-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" ^
-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" ^
-L"I:\Projects\VS\Real_DirectX11\common\lib" ^
-w -lkernel32 -luser32 -lole32 -ldxguid -luuid -ldxgi -ld3d11 -ld3dcompiler -ldirectxtex -o %cd%\bin\%1.exe
```

In the command line (assuming you're in the root of your project), I just simply write `build main` and hit the enter. Everything compiles just fine. I'm using the flag `-w` which is for suppressing all warnings. Why? Because if I don't use it, it will give hundreds of warnings related to the Windows SDK's files (though, I still check if my own code doesn't have warnings).

I loaded the texture with this code:

```
HRESULT result;
...
result = DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFile(d3d11_device, L"../textures/mdx.png", NULL, &texture);
if(FAILED(result))
{
    // handle the error
}
```

I don't know if I'm going into any troubles later in my DirectX 11 rendering engine... but I'll just hope that everything is going to be fine.

[image]